# Redux - keeping related reducers in sync

Tags: redux

I'm building an Angular 1.5 app right now that I am incrementally adding Redux to. I'm coming across a problem that I'm having a hard time finding a good solution for. My application mostly deals with widgets that display data and manage the configurations that define what data is displayed in those widgets. As I add more state to Redux, the widgets reducer is getting enormous. I have broken it up into a few smaller reducers but now I'm wondering about the maintainability of a setup like this.

Essentially I worry that in the future it will be far too easy to modify one reducer or add a new action that operates on widget data and then forget to adjust all of the other reducers to account for this new aspect of the system. Or that the various ways that widget state can change via the reducers will get so complicated that it will be prohibitively difficult to make sure that I have properly adjusted all of the reducers necessary.

A lot of these reducers essentially just need to react when a widget is removed/moved/modified/whatever. I wish there was a simple catch-all way to do that in Redux like a deep watch in vanilla Angular(I know deep watchers should be avoided generally but just as an example). As I convert more of my app to use Redux, these reducers will just get more and more complex. It seems like it's a losing game. Is there some different way of approaching this problem that would be more appropriate for this problem space? Or should I just accept that some reducers are going to be enormous and that is how it has to be? Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my specific problem is mostly to keep all state related to a given widget in one object so that I don't end up with redundant data management requirements. I split both state and reducers up and that caused the same logic for managing data cleanup and maintenance to be spread across different reducers. If I just split reducers up by implementing higher order reducers and keep the state in one place for one concept then this problem goes away.